# Regex for text marks in Bash and Sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
T='lorem . ipsum.lorem ....... ipsum........lorem'
echo "$T" | sed -e 's/\.\{3,\}/.../g' -e 's/ \. /\./g' -e 's/ \.\{3\} /.../g' -e 's/\.[^\.]/. /g'

lorem. psum. orem... psum... orem
```

However, the desired outcome is:

```
lorem. ipsum. lorem... ipsum... lorem
```

Thansk a lot.

Comment: You commented on two answers that you combined their ideas in a final answer. Why not post that answer yourself and accept it, so everybody knows you are satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r -e's/ *\.{2,} */... /g;s/ *\. */. /'{2,1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember the character you matched in the last `sed` part:
Replace

```
-e 's/\.[^\.]/. /g'
```

with

```
-e 's/\.\([^\.]\)/. \1/g'
```

EDIT:
You can make a shorter solution with

```
echo "${T// }" | sed -r 's/\.{3,}/.../g;s/(\.+)/\1 /g'
```

(This doesn't show what you did wrong, that's why I gave the other answer first)

Comment: Based on the answers, I'd better stay with: `sed -E -e 's/\.{3,}/.../g' -e 's/ \. /\./g' -e 's/ \.{3} /.../g' -e 's/\.([^\.])/. \1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -E -e 's/\.{4,}/.../g' -e 's/(\.)(\w)/\1 \2/g' -e 's/(\w) (\.)/\1\2/g' file
```

Output:

```
lorem. ipsum. lorem... ipsum... lorem
```

Comment: Based on the answers, I'd better stay with: `sed -E -e 's/\.{3,}/.../g' -e 's/ \. /\./g' -e 's/ \.{3} /.../g' -e 's/\.([^\.])/. \1/g'`